# Tracking user's online/offline state with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been thinking of a way of doing this but couldn't find a way so far. I want my users to see each others online/offline state, like in many social networks. For example, a boolean for each user. True means online and false is offline. But when do I set that boolean value to false? The moment user closes the application seems like a good moment but from my research, there is no guaranteed way to know if application is killed.

So, how would you guys track your users online state with Firebase or with your own server or whatever. I'm curious

By saying online and offline , I mean if the user is using the app at that moment.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides a convenient way to do this via the special `.info/connected` path

```
var amOnline = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://<demo>.firebaseio.com/presence/' + userid);
amOnline.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    // User is online.
    userRef.set(true);
  } else {
    // User is offline.
    // WARNING: This won't work! See an explanation below.
    userRef.set(false);
  }
});
```

Here is a nice explanation about tracking user states. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html

Answer (score -1):

You can set a listener for the internet connection. Like check if the internet is connected or not. If not connected then put the boolean to false and if the internet is connected then boolean will be true. Have a look at the code :

```
ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if(isConnected)   
    {
        // set your boolean to true
    }
    if(!isConnected) 
    {
        // set your boolean to false here
    }
```

Comment: You can opt for the service.

Comment: @Jack are you sure this code is according the question?

Comment: @Javacoder The code is not the 100% solution of the question but it would do most of the part like if the user has turned of the internet then set the boolean value to false. Complete answer would include the services, like he needs to set a kind of listener in the service to check if the app is still running in android process. If the app is closed like we normally do by swiping up the recent apps then again set the value of boolean false there. So, I helped him in the activity part.